# Rails page changing translations on every refresh

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, translation

I have a page on my Ruby on Rails app which is changing translations on every refresh. The tricky thing here is that it is only visible on the production instance and not on local. I have no clue how to solve this one!
It is a normal html.erb file.

Comment: What do you mean by changing translations, is it changing the language on every refresh? If that is so then you could check for the default locale setting and set that and also have a `before_action` on `ApplicationController` which sets the locale according to the chosen one or something similar (this is just an idea on how you might accomplish it)

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you're setting value to `I18n.locale` which can leak to other requests, see official docs for recommendations around this: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#managing-the-locale-across-requests